# Retrieve attendance from firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my `firebase` structure. I want to retrieve the attendance of a class  (select from `spinner`) and a subject(select from spinner). I don't want to retrieve data from `firebase`. What I want is the number of presents and absents of each student in each subject. Please check the image that's what I want to get.
[I want this kind of result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EuYJ.png)

```
"attendance":{  
"01-01-19":{  
  "BSCS 1st_A":{  
     "c++":{  
        "std1":{  
           "attendance":"absent",
           "id":"std1"
        },
        "std12":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std12"
        },
        "std2":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std2"
        },
        "std3":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std3"
        },
        "std4":{  
           "attendance":"absent",
           "id":"std4"
        }
     },
     "software engineering":{  
        "std1":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std1"
        },
        "std12":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std12"
        },
        "std2":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std2"
        },
        "std3":{  
           "attendance":"absent",
           "id":"std3"
        },
        "std4":{  
           "attendance":"absent",
           "id":"std4"
        }
     }
  }
},
"05-01-19":{  
  "BSCS 1st_A":{  
     "calculus":{  
        "std1":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std1"
        },
        "std12":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std12"
        },
        "std2":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std2"
        },
        "std3":{  
           "attendance":"absent",
           "id":"std3"
        },
        "std4":{  
           "attendance":"present",
           "id":"std4"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query firebase database like this:

```
final DatabaseReference dinosaursRef;
dinosaursRef.child("01-01-19").child("BSCS 1st_A").child("c++").whereEqualTo("attendance", "present")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                        int totalPresent= querySnapshot.size();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code snippet will give you number of `presents` in `BSCS 1st_A` and `c++` class. You can modify it according to your needs to get other `presents`, `absent`s and `classes`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I want to get number of presents and absents of each student.

Comment: I have added an image in my question. please check it. That's what I want to get.